# How can I extract information from .sam files?

Tags: samtools, sam, bowtie2

I have 10 `.sam` files after my `bowtie2` alignment on ten single-pair sequences. I would like to build a graph based on that output data, however I don't see any other solution but just writing the alignment percentage manually after each iteration.

Is there a tool that can help me to build a `.csv` file so I can manipulate the output data more easily?

Comment: You should *never* have SAM files: they’re not useful, *not even as intermediate files!* You should *always* directly generate BAM files. They’re smaller, more efficient, and allow more features (e.g. indexing for even faster access and statistics). For example, you would usually call bowtie2 as follows: `bowtie2 ‹args› | samtools sort --output-fmt-option level=0 | samtools view -b -o sorted.bam` (this immediately sorts the BAM file, which requires a lot of RAM; if this isn’t suitable for you, omit the intermediate step; but you normally want to have sorted BAMs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`samtools flagstat`](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-flagstat.html) with option `-O tsv`:

> Using **-O tsv** selects a tab-separated values format that can easily be imported into spreadsheet software. In this format the first column contains the values for QC-passed reads, the second column has the values for QC-failed reads and the third contains the category names.

**SEE ALSO:**
[What Does Samtools Flagstat Results Mean?](https://www.biostars.org/p/12475/)

**INSTALLATION:**
Some old versions of `samtools` do not have option `-O tsv`. To install a recent versions of `samtools`, use either:

[`conda`](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/samtools) (macOS, Linux) (but see also: [Tutorial: installing samtools with conda - overcoming two common errors](https://www.biostars.org/p/455593/)):

```
conda create --name samtools samtools
```

or [`brew`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/samtools) (macOS):

```
brew install samtools
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked however just in a "default" combination, e.g. samtools flagstat input.sam           If I try  samtools flagstat -O tsv input.sam, it throws me an error  invalid option -- 'O'

Comment: @DmitriiTrubetskoy See updated answer.

Comment: thanks, however my ``` samtools is already the newest version (1.7-1).``` (info from terminal). Just to be sure, the right syntax will be: ```samtools flagstat -O tsv input.sam``` ?

Comment: @DmitriiTrubetskoy Exactly, and note that `1.7*` is older than `1.11`, which is the most recent version available through both `conda` and `brew` (see links in my answer). I also confirmed that this option is present in `samtools 1.10` that I installed via `brew`. So try updating/installing the new `samtools` version if you really need this option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just wonder how can I roll back to ```1.10```? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @DmitriiTrubetskoy Don't roll back, because 1.7 is fairly old. I am suggesting *updating* from 1.7 to the most recent version, currently 1.11. Use conda or brew. To install conda (for mac or linux), follow directions here for miniconda: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/ . To install brew (for mac), follow the directions here: https://brew.sh/ . Then use the commands in my answer to install samtools (via conda **or** brew). This will install by default the most recent version. You are usually best off with the most recent version. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Now it worked, something happened...however I suppose I must have created some new file that would contain some output information - what kind of file that should be? I cannot see find anything in the same folder where ```input.sam``` file was.

Comment: @DmitriiTrubetskoy It writes into STDOUT a tsv file, 16 rows x 3 cols.

Comment: Great, now everything's ok. Much appreciated the tips and for being patient.